# Integrating arctan

Tags: integration

$x^2\over(1+x^2)$

Is there any other way to integrate this other than make the numerator $x^2 +1 -1$ and then split this into two integrals?

My smartass friend told me that this is the only way but I refuse, but I'm stupid I've spent couple of hours trying to think about this but never came up with anything.

Comment: Did you mean $$\displaystyle \int\left(1- \frac{1}{1+x^2} \right)\mathrm dx = x-\arctan(x) + C$$?

Comment: If you mean *any* other way, one way is trig substitution. Take a right triangle with legs $x$ and $1$ and $\theta$ opposite the side of length $x$. Then $x=\tan(\theta),dx=\sec^2(\theta) d \theta$ and $1+x^2=\sec(\theta)^2$ so you have $\int \tan(\theta)^2  d \theta$. This isn't hard to integrate once you use the identity $\tan(\theta)^2=\sec(\theta)^2-1$.

Answer (score 1):

Letting $x=tan(u)$ so $dx=sec^2(u)du$ also noting that $1+tan(u)^2=sec^2(u)$ the integral becomes $\int tan^2(u)du$.  This integral is pretty easy if you rearrange the previous trig identity to get $tan(u)^2=sec^2(u)-1$.

EDIT: I realized the back substitution is sort of non-trivial so I decided to add it.  Using $\int tan^2(u)du=\int sec^2(u)-1du$ we can split this up and $sec^2(u)$ is an elementary integral to take.  So we get $\int sec^2(u)-1du=\int sec^2(u)du-\int du=tan(u)-u+C$.  Now noting that we let $x=tan(u)$ so $arctan(x)=u$ and you just get $tan(arctan(x))-arctan(x)+C=x-arctan(x)+C$.

Comment: Of course, the trig identity winds up telling you to do almost exactly the same algebra as was suggested in the OP in the first place, it just gets suggested by trig rather than simply by intuition.

Comment: By the way, in elementary calculus they generally frown upon replacing a variable with itself.

Comment: @Ian Yeah I just got home from a long day and typed way too fast, fixed now!  Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 0):

Split x^2 into x*x. Do integration by parts, where u = x, dv = x/1+x^2. This will lead you to calculating the integral of ln(1+x^2), which is ugly, but can be done with certain trig substitutions.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{x^2}{1+x^2} = \frac{x^2}{(x+i)(x-i)} = \color{red}{x\left(\frac{A}{x+i} + \frac{B}{x-i}\right)}$$  $$A(x-i) + B(x+i) = x$$
$$-2iA = -i \implies A = 1/2$$
$$ 2iB = i \implies B = 1/2$$
This implies that we can rewrite our red fractions as such:
$$= \frac{x}{2(x+i)} + \frac{x}{2(x-i)}$$
We now use the substitutions $x+i = u$  and $x-i = v$ 
$$= \frac{u-i}{2u} + \frac{v+i}{2v}$$
If we now integrate these we get
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left(u-i\log(u) + v +i\log(v)\right)$$
$$= \frac{1}{2}\left(2x-i\log(x+i)+i\log(x-i)\right)$$
$$= x + \frac{i}{2}\left(\log(x-i)-\log(x+i)\right)$$
We now recognize the final term as a definition of inverse cotangent and the result follows. That might be the most absurd way to solve this, but hey... no adding or subtracting in the numerator!